# Remove childrens from JSON and produce a JSON with only parents?

Tags: javascript, json

I got the next JSON:

```
"thing":{ 
    "something":{
        "1":1,
        "2":2
    }
    "somethingelse":{
        "1":1,
        "2":2
    }
}
```

And i want to parse that JSON to this:

```
"thing":{
    "something1": 1,
    "something2": 2,
    "somethingelse1": 1,
    "somethingelse2": 2,
}
```

As you can see the names of the result elements are a concatenation of the parent and the children. And the value is the value of the children. Can anyone help me in how can I get this in JavaScript? Thanks.

Comment: A recursive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested loops to achieve this if you have only one level of nested properties:

```js
var thing = { 
    "something":{
        "1":1,
        "2":2
    },
    "somethingelse":{
        "1":1,
        "2":2
    }
};

var newThing = {};

for (var key in thing) {
  for (var subKey in thing[key]) {
    newThing[key + subKey] = thing[key][subKey];
  }
}

console.log(newThing);
```

If you have an arbitrary number of levels, recursion is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var jn = {
        "test": {
            "test": 1,
            "testx": 2,
            "xtest": {
                "x": 1,
                "y": 2
            },
            "test2": 1
        },
        "xx":{
            "x":2,
            "y": 3
        }
    };
  
  var flatJson = function(json, val, obj){
        var keys = Object.keys(json);
        
        for(var key in json){
            if(Object.keys(json[key]).length > 0){
                flatJson(json[key], val + key, obj);
            }
            else {
               obj[val + key] = json[key];
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }
    
    /* this is only as an example for your question, you could also call:
       flatJson(jn, "", {})  
    */

    var ret = flatJson(jn["test"], "", {});
    var out = {"test": ret }
    
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(out, undefined, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="out" ></pre>
```

The jn [...] is some test data. The function will simply traverse the keys and only if there are no keys it will take the value and add it to the variable obj. Otherwise it will call flatJson recursive with the parameters of the previous keys appended to the actual key and the obj variable, that will contain the object.

As arrays have no explicit name for each element it is implicitly named by the index, which is default in js.

To use it for your problem -- lets assume your json is called var js -- you can call it with `var out = flatJson(js["Thing"], "", {});` and then `var newJs = { "Thing" : out };` which leads to the output in your question.

Have fun.